# Is there a way to find out what applications on the phone register for certain intent?

Tags: android

Is there any way for me know what applications on the phone register for an Intent?
For example, for ACTION_SEND, i would like to know what applications are listening for it and allow user to select which I launch that intent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) has a set of queryXXX() methods you should check. The queryIntentActivities() or quertyIntentServices return all activities/services that can accept a particular intent.